# TYPO3 install LayerSlider

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am a bit beginner and my question may sounds basic but I am confused.
I want to install LayerSlider.
in the [installation manuel](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/layerslider/UsersManual/Index.html) it says :

> -Include the static TypoScript template "layerslider" in your root template!
>   -Check the constant editor "PLUGIN.TX_LAYERSLIDER (6)" for some setting about the include from jquery and other needed libraries. Use
>   always the latest jquery library!

This is the list of layerslider name starting files,

[image]

Which one I have to include?

Is this the right way to do it in the backend (where the ?????? marks)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the Static template of LayerSlider in

`Page --> Template--> Edit the whole template record-->'Includes' tab`

[Check this short video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4V5Y7ARdz0)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I missed